# Get-IISSite, sort bindings and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, iis

When I run the following cmdlets `Get-IISSite | select Name, Bindings` I get the IIS Site Names and the Bindings enumerated in a nice readable format like so:

Example 1

> Default Web Site {http *:80:}
>   Site 1 {http *:804:, http *:80:site1.mysite.net}

When I pipe that into the Export-Csv cmdlet `Get-IISSite | select Name, Bindings | Export-Csv c:\file.csv` I get the following output:

Example 2

> "Name","Bindings"
>   "Default Web Site","Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection"
>   "Site 1","Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection"`

I know the `Export-Csv` cmdlet calls `.ToString()` on each property of the object and that is why I am getting the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection` type name in what is the Bindings field. I have 2 questions:

1. How can I get an enumerated output to the CSV like example 1 displays?
2. How can I sort the items from the Bindings item as I wish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a calculated property which joins the bindings

```
Get-IISSite | Select-Object Name,@{n='Bindings';e={$_.Bindings -Join ', '}} | 
    Export-Csv c:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```